# It it possible to draw a figure with Paperjs, using different strokecolor in the same Path?

Tags: typescript, paperjs

The problem is:

I want to draw a figure with paperjs library (documentation [here](http://paperjs.org/)), and I would like to know if it is possible to draw it with paper.Path class using different stroke color in the same path.
The result that I've obtained is the following:

[Rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qk3ml.png)

I would like to use a different stroke color for the horizontal line in the middle of the rectangle.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can just draw a line in the middle of your rectangle, like in [this sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.7/S/hZAxT8QwDIX/SpSlqVSiglQJFTGxMQDiBgbCkCamjWqcKkm54XT/neauJxAg2PzJz89+3nHSb8BbvhkhmYFX3HibeWLXjGDLHnQa5COYpKlHEO8OtrLzM9koDVCCILW1oqkrdtGUFfulH+cuBW3SSVReKZpkTMGPcOPRh3XToRa3m/s7OekQQRQ7pngAq3jLatlUC/UBgI58mbnDGY54zvbFav3qEE/GBbp+SFlWfG59cjYNS7NRpAi/BBXZAL/dVviwZM/z+HMeD/H/+Epdlv+ozlbZ8vsugB4n7yhF3j6/7D8A).